# How to compare output of slow netcat client with a file

Tags: bash, netcat

```
readarray -t FILES < text.in

for ELEMENT in ${FILES[@]}
do
printf $ELEMENT
sleep 2
done | nc -q -1 localhost 5555
```

This code simulates a slow network client which sends a text line from text.in every 2 seconds to a key-value-store server with netcat.
How do I compare the output of netcat with a file test.out?

Example for text.in:

```
GET$5$hello
SET$5$hello$7$myworld
GET$5$hello
QUIT
```

Example for test.out:

```
ERR
OK
VALUE$7$myworld
```

Once the `QUIT` line is sent, the server closes the connection. After that I want to compare the standard output of netcat to test.out

I could do this: `nc localhost 5555 < text.in | diff - test.out` but then the entire file text.in is sent immediately which defeats the purpose of simulating a slow client.

I tried the following but it gets stuck and never returns anything:

```
readarray -t FILES < text.in

for ELEMENT in ${FILES[@]}
do
printf $ELEMENT
sleep 2
done | nc -q -1 localhost 5555 | diff - test.out
```

**EDIT: ANSWER IN COMMENTS**

Comment: Posting a little example netcat output with your command would be helpful, also a little example of what you have in test.out would be useful.

Comment: Are you comparing the log of `nc` to the file? I think the log is printed on stderr, so you may need `2>&1` to append `nc` stderr to stdout. The diff syntax for comparing stdin is fine. You should also quote your variables. Note that C escapes and format specifiers in `$ELEMENT` are expanded, unless you do `printf %s "$ELEMNENT"`. Also, instead of saying "it does not work", it's far more useful to say "I expected this ..., instead I got this ...".

Comment: In the end what I tried does work. It's just that I forgot to close the connection and netcat would not return and stay open forever.

Comment: Consider adding how you solved it as answer.